# Screenshot logs me out

Tags: screenshot, logout, debugging

As soon as I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScn</kbd> (which is supposed to take a screenshot of a window) instead it logs me out. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Check your keyboard shortcuts in the system settings.

Comment: `journalctl --since="-10 min" will show the last 10 minutes of logs, which may have a hint.

Comment: @wjandrea I did, it is not listed as a shortcut. I clicked on "Reset All", tried it again, and it still logged me out.

Comment: @waltinator Thanks, I checked, but I didn't see anything unusual.